# Questions about doors (and vault doors)

Tags: zombicide-black-plague

- Do I need to roll the dice to open a vault door? Or is it auto success?
- Can I close vault doors?
- Regarding opening doors in general: the rulebook, in page 19, explicitly says (emphasis mine):

> Melee weapons with the “Open a door” symbol can be used to
>   open a door next to the Survivor. Spend an Action and roll as
>   many dice as the weapon’s Dice value: the door is opened if
>   any die result equals or exceeds the Accuracy number of the
>   weapon. **Place a Noise token in the Zone.**

However, it seems obvious that you should only put a noise token if the weapon is noisy for opening doors. There is a bell in the opening door slot of the card to indicate that. Is this a problem in the manual?

Comment: Is there a weapon with the "open a door" symbol with a dice on it, without a bell on it?

Comment: @ikegami Not at the moment, but they're putting out their third expansion soon. They may have a noiseless weapon coming out in that or the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ***Do I need to roll the dice to open a vault door? Or is it auto success?***

It depends on the type of weapon used.

> Vault doors can be opened like standard doors (unless otherwise stated in the Quest’s description)
>
> Melee weapons with the “Open a door” symbol can be used to open a door next to the Survivor. Spend an Action and roll as many dice  as the weapon’s  Dice value: the door is opened if any die result equals or exceeds the Accuracy number of the weapon. Place a Noise token in the Zone.
>
> Some weapons have the “Open a door” symbol without a die symbol on it.  They can be used to open doors without the need to roll any dice. Just spend an Action to open the door. A Noise token is placed if the weapon is noisy (see Reading An Equipment Card, page 12)

---

> ***Can I close vault doors?***

You can't normally close a door (of any kind), but there's a skill that grants the ability.

> Lock it down – At the cost of one Action, the Survivor can close an open  door in his Zone. Opening or destroying it again later does not trigger a new Zombie Spawn.

It doesn't mention explicitly mention vault doors, but vault doors are opened just like any other door, so I would conclude they can be closed just like any other door too.

> Vault doors can be opened like standard doors (unless otherwise stated in the Quest’s description)

---

> ***It seems obvious that you should only put a noise token if the weapon is noisy for opening doors***

I agree. This is already explicitly stated for weapons with the "open a door" symbol without a die symbol on it.

> Some weapons have the “Open a door” symbol without a die symbol on it.  They can be used to open doors without the need to roll any dice. Just spend an Action to open the door. A Noise token is placed **if the weapon is noisy** (see Reading An Equipment Card, page 12)

(Emphasis mine)

I believe you will find there is no weapon with the "open a door" symbol with a die on it and without a bell on it. If you do find such a weapon, I agree that it shouldn't make noise when opening a door (although I'd check to see if the bell icon was accidentally left out first).